# Accented characters in Query Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

i would like to display the result this query :

`select t_req from table where t_req='TÉLITINO MORINOS'` but i return 0 lines but i have this lines in table contains the t_req='TÉLITINO MORINOS'.

How can i Get the résult in PL/SQL Oracle?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about this `t_req = N'TÉLITINO MORINOS'` or even `UPPER(t_req) = N'TÉLITINO MORINOS'`

Comment: It is possible that the row (not line! that means something different) so, that the row in your table that has the value `'TÉLITINO MORINOS'` in the `t_req` column actually does **not** have that value, but a different one that **looks** like it. (For example there may be a trailing space, or the space you see may be a nonbreaking space character, etc.) To make sure, find that row, and then `select dump(t_req) from table where ...` (the `where` clause identifies the row by primary key, for example). Then post the result here so we can analyze it.

Comment: Which tool do you use? What is your `NLS_LANG` setting?

Comment: @T.S aucune lines return i used cmd pl/sql  such as i have this value in the column t_req